# native notification Samsung Gear 2 Watch

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I want to integrate with the native Samsung Gear 2 Notifications such that when my consumer app in the Samsgung Gear 2 Watch receives a certain data from my host provider, the User will get a Notification in the Native notifications app. How can I accomplish this?

I've spent 50+ hours googling, looking up docs, etc but there doesn't seem to be an answer. The best resource I could find are the links below, but even these seem outdated and don't work at all.

Help please!

So I've been following these Guides but neither of them work for me :

https://developer.tizen.org/fr/documentation/articles/how-use-tizen-notification-api?langswitch=fr

also

https://developer.tizen.org/fr/documentation/articles/notifications?langredirect=1

The error I receive when running the sample code they provided:

```
TypeError:'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new tizen.StatusNotification("SIMPLE", "Simplenotification",notificationDict)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer is there is NO SUCH THING as native notifications for the Samsung Gear 2. That library is a private library owned by samsung only and only special people can have access to that. For the lay men the closest we can get is to enable notification via Gear Manager and have our paired phone relay notifications to the watch.

Comment: Hi Charles, where do you find the documents on relaying notifications? Is it standard Android Notification? like here http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html Thanks.